# How can I run ROS2 nodes in a debugger (e.g. gdb)?

Tags: ros, ros2, gdb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there something like the `--prefix` argument from rosrun in ros2 (see #q222530)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267261/how-can-i-run-ros2-nodes-in-a-debugger-(e.g.-gdb)?/) by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 775 on 2017-07-24

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `--prefix` argument is now working with `ros2 run`. So you can use it in the same way as known from rosrun, e.g.:

`ros2 run --prefix 'gdb -ex run --args' package_name executable_name` (see #q222530 for more examples).

At the moment this feature is only available on ROS2 installations, which were built from the development sources (master branch).

---

Originally posted by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) with karma: 775 on 2017-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 16

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [klintan](https://answers.ros.org/users/36546/klintan/) on 2019-09-11**:
I don't want to create a new question for this but; how would that be written for lldb ? probably trivial but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not an option like that. You can just run the binary directly from its location in `gdb <install_prefix>/lib/<package_name>/<executable_name>`. You can open an issue or pull request on `ros2 run` to make this case better:

https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) on 2017-07-24**:
Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Had some issues getting `gdb` running on Mac, so had to use LLDB instead:

Make sure to build with debugging symbols.
`colcon build --symlink-install --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo`

Further you can start your node by referencing the executables directly (in this case my packages is called `arke_base`):
`lldb -f arke_base/install/arke_base/lib/arke_base/arke_hardware_interface_node -- --ros-args --params-file arke_base/config/arke_diff_drive_controller.yaml`

The command also shows arguments added, in this case a config file.

---

Originally posted by [klintan](https://answers.ros.org/users/36546/klintan/) with karma: 11 on 2020-08-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I find a method to debug a C++ node usign VSCode on ROS2 Foxy (Ubuntu).

1. Compile your C++ package with the symbols:

   colcon build --symlink-install --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
2. Run the GDB Server in a localhost:port

   ros2 run --prefix 'gdbserver localhost:3000' package_name executable_name
3. Open VSCode on your workspace, open the debug section (side bar) and create new launch.json configuration file for debugging. Configure as follow:

   ```
    {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Debugger",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "miDebuggerServerAddress": "localhost:3000",
            "cwd": "/",
            "program": "[build-path-executable]"
        }
    ]
   ```

   }
   Change [build-path-executable] by your executable build file. You can find this path on the console when you launch the server.
4. Run the debugger and use VSCode to debug your code.

Here is a more detail explanation
https://gist.github.com/JADC362/a4425c2d05cdaadaaa71b697b674425f

---

Originally posted by [JADC362](https://answers.ros.org/users/73845/jadc362/) with karma: 81 on 2021-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-04-28**:
Can you please update your answer to include the relevant information from the link that you posted? Link-only answers are discouraged as links change, go down, etc. and if/when that happens then your answer won't be of much utility

**Comment by [JADC362](https://answers.ros.org/users/73845/jadc362/) on 2021-04-28**:
Sure. Updated :)

**Comment by [ffent](https://answers.ros.org/users/75061/ffent/) on 2021-05-25**:
Thank you for your great answer, but is there any similar way to debug composable nodes insight component containers? I'm really struggling to debug these nodes.

**Comment by [HiroIshida](https://answers.ros.org/users/85720/hiroishida/) on 2021-10-06**:
@flent I guess you can attach gdb process to existing process of the component conatiner.
like `gdb --pid $(ps -ef|grep your_container_name|awk NR==1'{print $2})'`

**Comment by [jd2548](https://answers.ros.org/users/119329/jd2548/) on 2022-09-29**:
How about in vscode? For nodes, I can use `--prefix` to add `gdbserver 127.0.0.1:3000` to start a server on a particular node, but a similar `--prefix` doesn't exist for components or Composable nodes